# SQL query to compare 3 tables and get answer

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me please with some sql query..

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
    id integer not null primary key,  -- id of car
    name text not null, -- car name
)
```

-- accidents

```
CREATE TABLE accidents (
    id integer not null primary key, -- id of accident
    place text not null, -- place of accident
    a_date date not null -- date of accident
)
```

-- results of accident

```
CREATE TABLE outcomes (
    car_id integer not null, -- id of car
    accident_id integer not null, -- id of accident
    result smallint not null, -- result: 0 - fine, 1 - scratched, 2 - crashed
    CONSTRAINT outcomes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (car_id, accident_id)
)
```

I need an sql query to get cars that was scratched once, and than was in accident again, of course crashed cars can't be in other accident.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select c.id, c.name, count(distinct o.results) cnt
from cars c
inner join outcomes o on c.id = o.car_id
where o.results in (1,2)
group by c.id, c.name
having count(distinct o.results) > 1;
```

Comment: almost! but that query doesn't return one that survived two accidents and crused on another... also it returns car that didnt even scratched...

Comment: I think you mentioned you wanted to show cars with a scratch and in accident. It should returns rows that are scratched because i'm doing `distinct count` on `results` column which will count 1 and 2 and if `count > 1` then the cars are both scratched and in accident. Can post some sample data or create [SQL Fiddle](http://http://sqlfiddle.com/)